# Pull out corresponding info from /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file called names.txt that holds a list of names. Some of these names do not correspond to names in /etc/passwd (5th field) and some do. For the names in the file that have users with the name I want to print their user name. For example if the name Bill Gates was in the names.txt file and this line is in `/etc/passwd bgates:x:23246:879:Bill Gates:/co/bgates:/bin/bash` I would print out "Bill Gates exists and has the username 'bgates'"

This is what I've been trying, but it just prints out the entire /etc/passwd file.

```
while read name; do

if cut -d: -f5 '/etc/passwd' | grep -q "$name"; then
        userName=$(cat /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f6)
        echo "$name exists and has the username $userName"
else
        echo "no such person '$line'"
fi
done < names.txt
```

Thank you

Comment: you could throw grep in there -- something like `$(cat /etc/passwd | grep -q $name | cut -d: -f6)`.  Better yet, do that once and test whether the string is empty instead of your `if cut...` test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -x
set -eu
set -o pipefail

function get_pwent_by_name
{
    full_name="$1"
    while read pwent
    do
        pw_full_name=$(echo "$pwent" | awk -F':' ' { print $5 }')
        if echo "$pw_full_name" | egrep -iq "$full_name"
        then
            echo "$pwent"
            break
        fi
    done < /etc/passwd
}

while read name
do
    pwent=$(get_pwent_by_name "$name")
    if [ "$pwent" != "" ]
    then
        userName=$(echo "$pwent" | awk -F':' ' { print $1 }')
        echo "$name exists and has the username $userName"
    else
        echo "No such person as $name"
    fi
done < names.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you accept to use awk to resolve your problem?

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$5]=$1;next} 
         {print ($0 in a)?$0 " exists and has the username " a[$0]:"no such person " $0}' /etc/passwd names.txt
```

Comment: I don't want to use something I don't understand. Thanks though.